# Find the values of $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ for which the recurrent sequence $x_{n+1} = 2^{\frac{x_n}{2}}$ has $2$ as its limit.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I am given the recurrent sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 0}$ with $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and:

### $$x_{n+1} = 2^{\frac{x_n}{2}}$$

and I am asked to find the interval of values for which this sequence has $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}x_n=2$. Also, if it is helpful (it didn't help me) I am given the following options:

**A.** $x \in \{2\}$

**B.** $x \in [-2, 2]$

**C.** $x \in (-\infty, 2]$

**D.** $x \in [2, 4)$

**E.** Other answer

I tried to take the logarithm of both sides, ending up with:

$$\ln(x_{n+1}) = \dfrac{x_n}{2} \ln (2)$$

$$2 \ln(x_{n+1}) = x_n \ln(2)$$

But I got nowhere with it. How should I approach something like this?

Comment: Note that if $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$ exists, then $x$ must satisfy $x = 2^{\frac x2}$.

Comment: @Math1000 And how can I use that to solve this problem? Using $x = 2^{\frac{x}{2}}$ and taking the logarithm of both sides, I get that the limit is either $2$ or $\infty$, which doesn't help since the problem statement already tells me that the limit is $2$.

Comment: Actually, $4$ is another solution to $x = 2^{\frac x2}$. But anyway, I suppose you are asking about values of $x_0$ such that the sequence converges to $2$? This was stated in your title but not in the question so I missed that. I would consider the map $x\mapsto 2^{\frac x2}$ and look at the behavior of its derivative.

Comment: @Math1000 Yes, that is what I need. The values of $x_0$ such that the sequence converges to $2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $2^{\frac{x}{2}}=x$ has the two solutions $x=2$ and $x=4$. Those are the only solutions since the derivative of $2^{\frac{x}{2}}$ is always increasing. Since $2^{\frac{x}{2}}$ and $x$ are continuous we get

$$2^{\frac{x}{2}}>x\Longleftrightarrow \begin{cases}x>4\\x<2\end{cases}$$

[image: Plot]

For any $x_n<2$ we get (since $2^{\frac{x}{2}}<2\Leftrightarrow \sqrt{2^x}<2\Leftrightarrow x<2$)

$$x_n<x_{n+1}<2$$

Thus for $x_0<2$ the sequence is increasing and bounded and therefore convergent. And as "Math1000" pointed out the limit $x$ must satisfy $x=2^{\frac{x}{2}}$ but since $x_n<2$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$ we get $x=2$.

For $2<x_0<4$ the sequence is decreasing and bounded by the same logic ($2^{\frac{x}{2}}<x\Leftrightarrow 2<x<4$) so the limit is $2$ here aswell.

For $x_0>4$ the sequence is increasing but has to diverge since the only possible limits are $2$ and $4$.

For $x=2$ or $x=4$ the sequence is constant. The sequence converges to $2$ for $x_0\in(-\infty,4)$ so the correct answers are **A**,**B**, **C** and **D**.

**Edit:** Here are the first few terms of the sequence for $x_0\in[-2,4.1]$:

[image: Plots]

(left click to open gif)

Comment: That's impossible! This question has multiple possible answers, but **only one** is correct. My textbook claims that the correct answer is **E.** (Other answer). Your answer seems logical, but there has to be just $1$ answer. I'm really confused by this exercise...

Comment: @user1502 then define **E** to be $x_0\in(-\infty,4)$ :)

Comment: I didn't understand how did you conclude the monotony of the sequence and whether the sequence is bounded or not for each of the cases. Why is it that for $x_0 < 2$ the sequence is increasing and bounded? Why is it decreasing and bounded when $2 < x_0 < 4$? Why is it increasing and divergent when $x_0 > 4$. And since you said that the only possible solutions to the equation $2^{\frac{x}{2}} = x$ are $x = 2$ **and** $x = 4$, how come the limit is never $4$?

Comment: @user1502 For any $x<2$ we have $2^\frac{x}{2}<2$ so if the sequence starts with $x_0<2$ it will always be less than $2$. Therefore the sequence is bounded. We also have $2^\frac{x}{2}>x$ for $x<2$ (see beginning of answer). Therefore the sequence is increasing. Use the same arguement for $2<x_0<4$ ($x_n>2$ and $x_{n+1}<x_n$). For $x_0>4$ the sequence is also increasing but can't converge since the only possible limits are $2$ and $4$ (see answer). Also the limit **is** equal to $4$ but only for $x_0=4$ (see answer).

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion, consider the function $f(x)=2^{x/2}$. Notice that $0<f'(2)<1$ and $f'(4)>1$. This will imply that $2$ is an attractor and $4$ is a repellent.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly is an attractor and repellent and what exactly do they do? I've never seen these terms used in mathematics before, and not being native in english certainly doesn't help.

Comment: 2 and 4 are fixe points of the system $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$. By atractor point, we mean a fix point $x_*$ around which all other starting points that are close enough, make the sequence closer and closer to $x_*$. A repellent in this case is the opposite, that is starting points near $x_*$ make the sequence move away from $x_*$.

Comment: Okay, I understand that, thanks for clarifying. **But**, $f'(x)$ is between $0$ and $1$ for negative values of $x$ too, while I am asked to find the values of $x$ for which the limit is $2$. So how do the negative numbers behave? Do they also approach $2$? Do they approach something else? How can I tell? And how can I use this to find the answer of my problem.

Comment: what matters is whether $|f'(x_*)|<1$ or $|f'(x_*)|>1$. in one-dimensional problems, you can use the mean value theorem the see how far (or closer) the values of the sequence are getting from the fixed point. Also, you may want to look at contractive maps and the Banach fixe point theorem for more information about local behavior o f the map $f$